# Disable repainting after modifying graph in Jung

Tags: java, graph, jung

I've a graph in Jung shown using a JFrame. 
After I remove a vertex from the graph,
the shown graph automatically redrawn and presented without the removed vertex.

How can I disable it, so that only when I call the repaint method 
the graph would be redrawn ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this is extend your graph by some class and add `toRemove()` method, where you can signify your vertex to delete in `boolean array`. And the second method `deleteNow()` which will use your boolean array and delete your vertexes - it will be alike `repaint()` now. The second way is add boolean value to your vertex instead of array in your extended class. I can't find any other way. Sorry if it's not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given enough information to be able to advise you precisely, but here are some general observations.

The answer to your question is going to depend in part on how you're removing the vertex: interactively or programmatically.

If it's programmatically, then you'll need to look at the code that calls `VisualizationViewer.repaint()`.  It's been a while since I've looked at that part of the code, but the gist is that something is listening to changes to the graph model and triggering repaints (because this is what users generally want).

If it's interactively, then it's probably on the same thread as your visualization, and you should have a fair amount of control over when `repaint()` gets called (see the calls in the sample code to `VV.repaint()`).